# How to Update a single field in MongoDB?

Tags: angular, mongodb, spring-boot

I am using Angular + Spring Boot + MongoDB for my project. I am trying to update just a single field. When I am trying it in Postman, all the other fields become `null`. How can I update just a single field?

I am using Postman for testing and would like to use this function in Angular in the future.

DateStorageRepository

```
package com.indsys.TravBackEnd.repositories;

import com.indsys.TravBackEnd.models.DateStorage;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@ComponentScan({"com.indsys.TravBackEnd"})
@EntityScan("com.indsys.TravBackEnd")
public interface DateStorageRepository extends MongoRepository<DateStorage, String> {
}
```

DateStorageController

```
package com.indsys.TravBackEnd.controllers;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.indsys.TravBackEnd.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.indsys.TravBackEnd.models.DateStorage;
import com.indsys.TravBackEnd.repositories.DateStorageRepository;

@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DateStorageController {
    @Autowired
    private DateStorageRepository dateStorageRepository;

    @GetMapping("/datestorage")
    public List<DateStorage> getAllDateStorages() {
        return dateStorageRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/datestorage/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<DateStorage> getDateStorageById(@PathVariable(value = "id") String dateStorageId)
            throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        DateStorage dateStorage = dateStorageRepository.findById(dateStorageId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("DateStorage not found for this id :: " + dateStorageId));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(dateStorage);
    }

    @PostMapping("/datestorage")
    public DateStorage createDateStorage(@Validated @RequestBody DateStorage dateStorage) {
        return dateStorageRepository.save(dateStorage);
    }

    @PutMapping("/datestorage/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<DateStorage> updateDateStorage(@PathVariable(value = "id") String dateStorageId,
            @Validated @RequestBody DateStorage dateStorageDetails) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
                DateStorage dateStorage = dateStorageRepository.findById(dateStorageId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("DateStorage not found for this id :: " + dateStorageId));
        dateStorage.setMtransactionID(dateStorageDetails.getMtransactionID());
        dateStorage.setStartDate(dateStorageDetails.getStartDate());
        dateStorage.setEndDate(dateStorageDetails.getEndDate());
        final DateStorage updatedDateStorage = dateStorageRepository.save(dateStorage);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedDateStorage);
    }
    

    @DeleteMapping("/datestorage/{id}")
    public Map<String, Boolean> deleteDateStorage(@PathVariable(value = "id") String dateStorageId)
            throws ResourceNotFoundException {
                DateStorage dateStorage = dateStorageRepository.findById(dateStorageId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Colours not found for this id :: " + dateStorageId));

        dateStorageRepository.delete(dateStorage);
        Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);
        return response;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you meant that you want to update only one field with the updateDateStorage route (for example, only the MtransactionId) ,then I would recommand you to check all the fields for null values like this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(dateStorageDetails.getMtransactionID())
            .ifPresent(x -> dateStorage.setMtransactionID(x));
```

Do this for every one of the fields and then it will update only the fields that you entered on postman...